# Error de servidor en la aplicación '/' No se ha encontrado la ruta de acceso de la red

Tags: c#, sql-server

Al ejecutar mi proyecto me sale este error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): No se ha encontrado la ruta de acceso de
>   la red]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Error relacionado con la red o específico
>   de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor
>   SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible.
>   Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server
>   está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se pudo abrir una conexión con SQL
>   Server)]
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +153
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) +336
>   SqlDependencyProcessDispatcher.StartWithDefault(String
>   connectionString, String& server, DbConnectionPoolIdentity& identity,
>   String& user, String& database, String& service, String appDomainKey,
>   SqlDependencyPerAppDomainDispatcher dispatcher, Boolean&
>   errorOccurred, Boolean& appDomainStart) +0
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(String connectionString,
>   String queue, Boolean useDefaults) +1095
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(String connectionString) +13
>   Customer.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in D:\Escritorio\Nueva
>   carpeta
>   (3)\SignalR-SQL_Dependency-master\Customer\Customer\Global.asax.cs:22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa tu ruta, porque la que estas enviando en tu aplicacion es esta `D:\Escritorio\Nueva carpeta (3)\SignalR-SQL_Dependency-master\Customer\Customer\Global.asax.cs:22`, verifica que sea la ruta correcta porque principalmente ahi esta el error

Comment: Validare la ruta y te estare comentando el resultado